# Text is cutting at the edges of textview android

Tags: android, layout, textview

I am using a custom font to display Hindi, and the font characters are cutting at left and right edges.  Below is the screenshot of my app.  I have already used padding, but it seems to make the font cut even more.

[image]

Here you can see I have just used two textview only, with "match_parent" for both of their widths.

The code is as follows:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/resultTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/background_color" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEng"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewGuj"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use padding with text view.

Comment: i have already used padding, but by use of that the font is much more cutting :(

Comment: Share your layout code..

Comment: Hi @PankajKumar i have updated

Comment: You can check the solution found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/17782522#17782522.